# Center Div scroll

Tags: css

In my code,
Within one container Three blocks will be there. one freezes on the left and one freezes on the right and the other will scroll in between these two divs. Just like modern grids. But I don't want to use the grid.

I have tried, but the center block is not getting the Horizontal scroll.
I want no breakage of the center block, instead, it should scroll horizontally.

```css
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .container {
   width: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
   white-space: nowrap
  }
  
  .scroll-center {
   width: auto;
   overflow: auto;
   display: block;
   white-space: nowrap
  }
  
  .row {
   float: left;
  }
  
  .cell {
   padding: 3px;
   border: 1px solid #bbb;
   min-height: 25px;
   min-width: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">HeaderL1</div>
    <div class="cell">HeaderL2</div>
    <div class="cell">HeaderL3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-center">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">HeaderT2</div>
    <div class="cell">Data21</div>
    <div class="cell">Data22</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">HeaderT3</div>
    <div class="cell">Data31</div>
    <div class="cell">Data32</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">HeaderT4</div>
    <div class="cell">Data41</div>
    <div class="cell">Data42</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">HeaderT5</div>
    <div class="cell">Data51</div>
    <div class="cell">Data52</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">HeaderT6</div>
    <div class="cell">Data61</div>
    <div class="cell">Data62</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">HeaderT7</div>
    <div class="cell">Data71</div>
    <div class="cell">Data72</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">HeaderT8</div>
    <div class="cell">Data81</div>
    <div class="cell">Data82</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">HeaderT9</div>
    <div class="cell">Data91</div>
    <div class="cell">Data92</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">HeaderTR</div>
    <div class="cell">DataR1</div>
    <div class="cell">DataR2</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried with .scroll-center { overflow: scroll };

Comment: Yes, I have tried, but not worked as expected.

Comment: But pratically you would like have 3 coloumn with center with vertical scroll ?

Comment: Actually, I need a horizontal scroll. I have updated my post please go through it once.
>I have tried, but the center block is not getting the Horizontal scroll. I want no breakage of the center block, instead, it should scroll horizontally.

Thank you. @LorenzoBerti

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add width to your container. Right now it's set to 100% so it will not size beyond the browser window. Instead you could do something like this:

```
.container {
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
     width:2000px;
}
```

I realize that you may need to change this value dynamically but hopefully this gets you started

Example:http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/jAjbdK

Comment: It is not working even in your codepen.io code. I need **right block** should be **next to center block** not below it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with For example:

css:

```
* {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
.left, .center, .right{
          float:left

 }


        .center {
            width:400px;
            overflow: scroll;
            display: block;
            white-space: nowrap
        }
    #center-scroll{
      width:2000px;
    }
    .center .row{
          display:inline-block;
      width:33%;
        }
    .center .row .cell{

      min-width:100%;
        }


        .row{
          float:left;
        }
        .cell {
            padding: 3px;
            border: 1px solid #bbb;
            min-height: 25px;
            min-width: 200px;
        }
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
  <div class="row" >
          <div class="cell">HeaderL1</div>
          <div class="cell">HeaderL2</div>
          <div class="cell">HeaderL3</div>
        </div>

  </div>

        <div class="center">
     <div id="center-scroll">
     <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">HeaderT2</div>
                <div class="cell">Data21</div>
                <div class="cell">Data22</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">HeaderT3</div>
                <div class="cell">Data31</div>
                <div class="cell">Data32</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">HeaderT4</div>
                <div class="cell">Data41</div>
                <div class="cell">Data42</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">HeaderT5</div>
                <div class="cell">Data51</div>
                <div class="cell">Data52</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">HeaderT6</div>
                <div class="cell">Data61</div>
                <div class="cell">Data62</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">HeaderT7</div>
                <div class="cell">Data71</div>
                <div class="cell">Data72</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">HeaderT8</div>
                <div class="cell">Data81</div>
                <div class="cell">Data82</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">HeaderT9</div>
                <div class="cell">Data91</div>
                <div class="cell">Data92</div>
            </div>
     </div>

        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">HeaderTR</div>
                <div class="cell">DataR1</div>
                <div class="cell">DataR2</div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It seems worked out. but this is not what I want. Within center block all row  blocks are come down. I want no breakage actully. Thank you.